# convert html or rgb color to system.drawing.brush

Tags: vb.net, winforms, colors, listbox

I want to convert html color e.g #FFFFD2 or RGB 255,255,210 to its brush color equivalent.
am doing this in the listbox_drawitem event. see the sample code am using, i got from internet, buts its not working.I want to paint the listitem background with this color, but the items background gets painted white

```
dim col as string = "#FFFFFF"
Dim myBrush as Brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromARGB(Integer.Parse( col.Substring( 1 ), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber ) ) )
```

can anybody help?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use ColorTranslator.FromHtml() method. This method will return Color class.

```
Dim b as new SolidBrush(ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFFFD2"))
```